# When should I close this database connection?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm writing a script to modify all entries in a database. Here is a start to log them all.

```
 MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb", { useNewUrlParser: true } ),

(async () =>{
    let client;
    try {
        client = await MongoClient;
        let collection = client.db("booliscraper").collection("sold");
        let docs = await collection.find();
        docs.forEach((doc) => { 
            console.log(doc);
        })

  } catch(err) {
    log(err)
  }
})();
```

This works fine, but I want to close the db-connection somehow. I tried closing it outsidthe try/catch, but that seems to close the connection before all items are itterated through. Don't understand why.

```
...
  } catch(err) {
    log(err)
  }
  client.close();
})();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add finally block and close MongoDB connection there

```
(async () => {
let client;
try {
    client = await MongoClient;
    let collection = client.db("booliscraper").collection("sold");
    let docs = await collection.find();
    await docs.forEach((doc) => {
        console.log(doc);
    })

} catch (err) {
    log(err)
} finally {
    client.close()
}})();
```

Here is reference  [try...catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch)

Comment: Won't work if you don't `await` the `docs.forEach()` though. It is the exact same problem as OP was having, really.

Comment: As @MadWard suggested, He can `await` the `docs.forEach`, I have updated code

Answer (score 2):

`docs`, the result of `<Collection>.find()`, is a cursor; and `<Cursor>.forEach()` is an async function.

Meaning your `client.close()` effectively gets called before you finished iterating over the cursor.

You may pass a second callback to forEach, that gets executed once the cursor has been exhausted:

```
MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb", { useNewUrlParser: true } ),

(async () =>{
    let client;
    try {
        client = await MongoClient;
        let collection = client.db("booliscraper").collection("sold");
        let docs = await collection.find();
        docs.forEach((doc) => { 
            console.log(doc);
        }, () => {
            //cursor is exhausted, close connection
            client.close();
        })

  } catch(err) {
    log(err)
  }
})();
```

For more information, this is documented in the [Node.js Mongo DB Driver API](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/Cursor.html#forEach).

Comment: Or, sticking with the `async` / `await` syntax `await docs.forEach(...); client.close();`

Comment: Indeed! I didn't go for it because it is not specified in the API, but `forEach()` **does** return a promise if no callback is passed.

Comment: nice, I thought about the native forEach, didn't think about the fact that this is an entirely different method.